# Using Element.insertAdjacentHTML to add 'Blocks' of HTML

Tags: html, inserthtml

I'm trying to insert the following 'block' of HTML using **Element.insertAdjacentHTML()**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <ul>
   <li class="go-back-environment">
    <a href="/environment">
     <p>Back to Environment</p>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="back-home">
    <a href="/home">
     <p>Back to home</p>
    </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

However, I'm not sure it is possible to add divs with classes and lists. I've been trying to find (unsuccessfully) articles with examples where more than one 'p' or 'span' was added.
I started with the following but I don't know how to continue building:

***var footer = document.getElementById ('environment');
footer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','')***

I tried the following:

```
 <script>
    var footer = document.getElementById ('environment');
    footer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 
    '<div class="content-wrapper">
      <ul>
       <li class="go-back-environment">
        <a href="/environment">
         <p>Back to Environment</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li class="back-home">
        <a href="/home">
         <p>Back to home</p>
        </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div> ');
  </script>
```

Is it even possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: What problem are you facing when you use this, in the example above you are taking variable ```footer``` but than using ```environment``` variable which is wrong.

Comment: Hey! Good spot. One mistake less to solve :) The issue to follow is how to add that piece of HTML I want to add :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Try using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for longer html strings:

```js
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');

var html = `
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <ul>
   <li class="go-back-environment">
    <a href="/environment">
     <p>Back to Environment</p>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="back-home">
    <a href="/home">
     <p>Back to home</p>
    </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div> 
`;

footer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
```

```html
<main>Main</main>
<footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! It worked ! :) I was about to ask if the classes would bring the style applied in an extrenal CSS file but it seems it does !  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey there @DanielSixl ! I've got another question. So, this script works when It is written within the html file. I've created a 'Global JS' file to host the script and then link to my HTML. But it seems that the script doesn't trigger this way. Have you done this before ? I might be linking incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it should not matter. Check your link to the script – it's a very common source of error and it is very easy to get it wrong. *But*, you maybe shouldn't use a global script. Your target element may not be existent on every page (you can check for existence, though). Or you might not want the list added on every single page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have done some mistake in string

Check for this

```js
var footer = document.getElementById('environment');

var appendHtml = ['<div class="content-wrapper">',
    '<ul>',
    '<li class = "go-back-environment">',
    '<a href = "/environment">',
    '<p> Back to Environment </p>',
    '</a>',
    '</li>',
    '<li class = "back-home">',
    '<a href = "/home">',
    '<p> Back to home </p>',
    '</a>',
    '</li>',
    '</ul>', 
    '</div>'].join("");
footer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', appendHtml);
```

```html
<div id=environment>Footer Div</div>
```